# Differentiate the following power series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{(2x-2)^n}{n2^n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

I am having issues with the differentiation of the following power series

$$ \large f(x) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{(2x-2)^n}{n2^n+1}$$

I get the following result

$$ \large f'(x) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{n(2x-2)^{n-1}}{n2^n+1}$$

but according to my professor the result is

$$ \large f'(x) =  \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{2n(2x-2)^{n-1}}{2n2^{n-1}+1}.$$

Can someone explain this to me or give me a hint on what I am doing wrong?

Best regards Husky

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(2x-2)^n=n(2x-2)^{n-1}2$ ... the denominator stays the same..

Comment: @nospoon Ahh okay, so the answer my professor provided me with is not correct? I now get it, thank you. I had similar exercises  but I  was completely confused when I saw that the denominator was changed.

Comment: @Husky653 it is correct! the denominator hasn't changed a bit! $2n2^{n-1}=n2^n$

Comment: the last one is actually correct since $2*2^{n-1} = 2^n$

Comment: sorry I was a bit slow! haha I just realized it, I guess i just looked at (n-1) and assummed it was changed haha

Comment: @nospoon sorry for bothering you again my professor does the following 
$\sum _{n \geq 1} \dfrac{2n(2x-2)^{n-1}}{2n2^{n-1}+1} = \sum _{m \geq 1} \dfrac{(2x-2)^{m}}{2^{m}+1}$
 I can't really figure out how the $2n$ is removed?

Comment: are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Yes, I will try to post a picture of it. @nospoon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26998/discussion-between-nospoon-and-husky653).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: refer to the *chain rule*.

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \Big((2x -2)^n \Big) = n (2x-2)^{n-1} \dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(2x -2 \Big)  = 2n(2x-2)^{n-1}
$$
Therefore 
$$
\dfrac{df}{dx} =  \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{(2x-2)^n}{n2^n+1}\right)
=  \sum_{n \geq 1}\left( \dfrac{1}{n2^n+1} \dfrac{d}{dx} \left((2x-2)^n\right)\right)
= \sum_{n \geq 1}\dfrac{2n(2x-2)^{n-1}}{n2^n+1} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that:
$$\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}$$

In you case $f(g(x))=(2x-2)^n$ where $g(x)=2x$, so $\dfrac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}=2$ and $\dfrac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial g(x)}=n(2x-2)^{n-1}$ etc...

Answer (score 1):

[image: Here is a picture of what my professor rewrites it too]

I hope this works. The text around the sum is in danish so try to ignore that, but my professor rewrites the power series and I can't really see how he removes the $2n$.

Comment: @nospoon Here is a picture of the result I am provided with